# GSON is there a way to bring in null and missing attribute to "" in GSON AND marshal ""/null back to missing attribute?

Tags: jackson, gson

Dealing with null strings in Database -> not fun.  unique constraints don't work well in those cases but do on "".  Therefore, we want java to act like a language with no nulls when it comes to String at least as we hacked this for jackson which doesn't fully support this use case in a not so good way.

We would like to read json like this

```
{
   "nullEx": null
} //not missing attribute
```

into this

```
public class Request {
   private String nullEx;
   private String missingAttr;
}
```

such that nullEx="" and missingAttr="" AFTER we read it in.  Developers are forgetting to default all Strings in DTOs = "" so to prevent this mistake going forward, we just want to read it all into the fields as ""!!!

Then on the way out, we want nullEx="" and missingAttr="" to marshal out to json { } ...ie. we don't write those attributes since they are blank.

Is there a way to do this in GSON?  This makes compatibility all the way through to the database much easier and we can use @NotBlank for bean validation and constraints work better.  In addition, developers no longer have to check for null AND trim if not null and check if empty(after trimming).  instead we just str.isBlank() on the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In addition, developers no longer have to check for null AND trim if not null and check if empty(after trimming). instead we just str.isBlank() on the String.

You might also consider using nullability checkers or code-generators to default values (if any of these is appropriate in your case, of course).
I personally would rather stick to JSR-305 and write corresponding `null`-tolerant `String` utility methods in order not to mimic NPE-safety and not to make `null` and `""` ambiguous.
Otherwise making Gson responsible for defaults may be both expensive and even harmful.

Here is one of possible solutions of doing that in Gson if you're really fine with the mentioned above.
(includes Java 8, imports from Apache Commons Lang (to clone objects to be pre-processed) and Google Guava):

```java
final class DefaultsTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final Predicate<? super Class<?>> supportClass;
    private final Predicate<? super Field> supportField;
    private final Function<? super Field, ?> toDefault;

    private DefaultsTypeAdapterFactory(final Predicate<? super Class<?>> supportClass, final Predicate<? super Field> supportField,
            final Function<? super Field, ?> toDefault) {
        this.supportClass = supportClass;
        this.supportField = supportField;
        this.toDefault = toDefault;
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory get(final Predicate<? super Class<?>> supportClass, final Predicate<? super Field> supportField,
            final Function<? super Field, ?> toDefault) {
        return new DefaultsTypeAdapterFactory(supportClass, supportField, toDefault);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final Class<?> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        if ( !supportClass.test(rawType) ) {
            return null;
        }
        final Collection<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Class<?> c = typeToken.getRawType(); c != Object.class; c = c.getSuperclass() ) {
            for ( final Field f : c.getDeclaredFields() ) {
                if ( supportField.test(f) ) {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    fields.add(f);
                }
            }
        }
        if ( fields.isEmpty() ) {
            return null;
        }
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                    throws IOException {
                try {
                    delegateTypeAdapter.write(out, preProcess(value, fields));
                } catch ( final IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                try {
                    return postProcess(delegateTypeAdapter.read(in), fields);
                } catch ( final IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                    throw new JsonParseException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
                .nullSafe();
    }

    private <T> T preProcess(final T value, final Iterable<Field> fields)
            throws IllegalAccessException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final T shallowCopy = (T) SerializationUtils.clone((Serializable) value); // or implement a non-Serializable version
        for ( final Field f : fields ) {
            @Nullable
            final Object fieldValue = f.get(shallowCopy);
            if ( fieldValue != null ) {
                @Nullable
                final Object defaultValue = toDefault.apply(f);
                if ( fieldValue.equals(defaultValue) ) {
                    f.set(shallowCopy, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return shallowCopy;
    }

    private <T> T postProcess(final T value, final Iterable<Field> fields)
            throws IllegalAccessException {
        for ( final Field f : fields ) {
            @Nullable
            final Object fieldValue = f.get(value);
            if ( fieldValue == null ) {
                f.set(value, toDefault.apply(f));
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

As the above type adapter is pretty configurable, you can define your to/from-default strategies on your own.
For example,

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface UseDefaults {
}
```

```java
@UseDefaults
final class Request
        implements Serializable { // must implement Serializable to be cloneable

    String nullEx;
    String missingAttr;

}
```

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, ?> defaults = new ImmutableMap.Builder<Class<?>, Object>()
        .put(String.class, "")
        .put(Boolean.class, false)
        .put(Byte.class, (byte) 0)
        .put(Short.class, (short) 0)
        .put(Integer.class, 0)
        .put(Long.class, 0L)
        .put(Float.class, 0F)
        .put(Double.class, 0D)
        .put(Character.class, '\u0000')
        .build();

private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(DefaultsTypeAdapterFactory.get(
                c -> c.isAnnotationPresent(UseDefaults.class), // handle only UseDefault-annotated classes
                f -> !f.getType().isPrimitive(), // handle non-primitive classes only
                f -> defaults.get(f.getType())
        ))
        .create();
```

Having that implemented makes the following unit test pass:

```java
final Request request = gson.fromJson("{\"nullEx\":\"\"}", Request.class);
Assertions.assertEquals("", request.nullEx);
Assertions.assertEquals("", request.missingAttr);
Assertions.assertEquals("retained", request.retained);
final String json = gson.toJson(request, Request.class);
Assertions.assertEquals("{\"retained\":\"retained\"}", json);
```

Comment: thanks @fluffy. I did forget to mention it also makes us closer to grpc which does not support null across the wire so you receive "" instead.  The mismatch is very annoying.  we.  I was hoping for a simpler solution :(.  thanks though!!! it's insightful.

Comment: that is a pretty sick example @fluffy !! btw.  just finished understanding it now too.  I love how you added a test.